# How to export spreadsheet data into SQLServer?

Tags: vba, excel

---

I am new to Vba, hope someone will solve my problem. I am trying to update data present in my spreadsheet. Actually i have 20,000 records, each record has around 74 columns. So updating them record by record by using ADO taking so much of time. Is there any alternative approach to update those records in single shot. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

---

Currently my code is.

---

```
    Sub InitialExport()
      On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Query As String
    Dim EffectedRecs As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    ServerName = "192.178.78.36"

    'Setting ConnectionString
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=" & ServerName & "; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=AppEmp;" & _
            "User ID=sa; Password=admin08; "

    'Setting provider Name
    con.Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.12.0"

    'Opening connection
    con.Open
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export")
    For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        '---------------------->
        EmpId = .Range("B" & i).Value 'Emp Code-varchar
        C = .Range("C" & i).Value 'Emp Name-varchar
        D = .Range("D" & i).Value 
        E = .Range("E" & i).Value 
        F = .Range("F" & i).Value 
        G = .Range("G" & i).Value 
        H = .Range("H" & i).Value
        II = .Range("I" & i).Value 
        JJ = .Range("J" & i).Value 
        k = .Range("K" & i).Value 
        l = .Range("L" & i).Value 
        M = .Range("M" & i).Value 

        N = CheckNull(.Range("N" & i).Value)
        O = CheckNull(.Range("O" & i).Value) 
        P = CheckNull(.Range("P" & i).Value) 
        Q = CheckNull(.Range("Q" & i).Value) 
        R = CheckNull(.Range("R" & i).Value) 
        S = .Range("S" & i).Value 
        T = .Range("T" & i).Value 
        U = .Range("U" & i).Value 
        v = .Range("V" & i).Value 
        W = .Range("W" & i).Value
        X = CheckNull(.Range("X" & i).Value)

        Y = .Range("Y" & i).Value 
        Z = .Range("Z" & i).Value 
        AA = CheckNull(.Range("AA" & i).Value)
        AB = .Range("AB" & i).Value 
        AC = CheckNull(.Range("AC" & i).Value) 
        AD = CheckNull(.Range("AD" & i).Value) 
        AE = CheckNull(.Range("AE" & i).Value) 
        AF = CheckNull(.Range("AF" & i).Value)
        AG = .Range("AG" & i).Value 
        AH = CheckNull(.Range("AH" & i).Value) 
        AI = CheckNull(.Range("AI" & i).Value) 
        AJ = CheckNull(.Range("AJ" & i).Value) 
        AK = CheckNull(.Range("AK" & i).Value)
        AL = CheckNull(.Range("AL" & i).Value) 
        AM = CheckNull(.Range("AM" & i).Value)
        AN = CheckNull(.Range("AN" & i).Value) 
        AO = CheckNull(.Range("AO" & i).Value) 
        AP = CheckNull(.Range("AP" & i).Value) 
        AQ = CheckNull(.Range("AQ" & i).Value)
        AR = CheckNull(.Range("AR" & i).Value) 
        aAS = CheckNull(.Range("AS" & i).Value) 
        AT = .Range("AT" & i).Value
        AU = CheckNull(.Range("AU" & i).Value) 
        AV = CheckNull(.Range("AV" & i).Value) 
        AW = CheckNull(.Range("AW" & i).Value) 
        AX = CheckNull(.Range("AX" & i).Value) 
        AY = CheckNull(.Range("AY" & i).Value) 
        AZ = CheckNull(.Range("AZ" & i).Value) 
        BA = CheckNull(.Range("BA" & i).Value) 
        BB = CheckNull(.Range("BB" & i).Value)
        BC = CheckNull(.Range("BC" & i).Value) 
        BD = CheckNull(.Range("BD" & i).Value)
        BE = .Range("BE" & i).Value 

        BF = .Range("BF" & i).Value 
        BG = CheckNull(.Range("BG" & i).Value) 
        BH = .Range("BH" & i).Value 
        BI = .Range("BI" & i).Value 
        BJ = CheckNull(.Range("BJ" & i).Value) 
        BK = CheckNull(.Range("BK" & i).Value) 
        BL = CheckNull(.Range("BL" & i).Value) 
        BM = .Range("BM" & i).Value 
        BN = .Range("BN" & i).Value 



        Query = "Exec HRApp_P_AddEmpData '" & EmpId & "','" & C & "','" & D & "','" & E & "','" & F & "','" & G & "','" & H & "','" & II & "','" & JJ & "','" & k & "','" & l & "','" & M & "'," & N & "," & O & "," & P & "," & Q & "," & R & ",'" & S & "','" & T & "','" & U & "','" & v & "','" & W & "'," & X & ",'" & Y & "','" & Z & "'," & AA & ",'" & AB & "'," & AC & "," & AD & "," & AE & "," & AF & ",'" & AG & "'," & AH & "," & AI & "," & AJ & "," & AK & ",'" & AL & "'," & AM & "," & AN & "," & AO & "," & AP & "," & AQ & "," & AR & "," & aAS & ",'" & AT & "'," & AU & "," & AV & "," & AW & "," & AX & "," & AY & "," & AZ & "," & BA & "," & BB & "," & BC & "," & BD & ",'" & BE & "','" & BF & "'," & BG & ",'" & BH & "','" & BI & "'," & BJ & "," & BK & "," & BL & ",'" & BM & "','" & BN & "'"

        con.Execute Query

    Next
    End With

     con.Close
     Set con = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:     'MsgBox "The Not able ta Save Data"

                Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

The above code is working fine. But it is taking more time to update data.:-(

---

Now my code became like this

---

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim adoConn             As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoRS               As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sQuery              As String
    Dim EffectedRecs        As Long
    Dim sFields             As String
    Dim sValues             As String

    Dim iRow                As Integer
    Dim iField              As Integer

    ServerName = "193.128.125.14"
    con_Str = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=" & ServerName & "; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=DB_At&T;" & _
            "User ID=sa; Password=ad28; "

    sQuery = "select * from Currency where 1=2"

    sValues = ""

    With adoConn
        .ConnectionString = con_Str
        .Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.12.0"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    With adoRS
        .ActiveConnection = adoConn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset ' adOpenDynamic
        .Source = sQuery
        .Open
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export")
        For iRow = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
            For iField = 0 To adoRS.Fields.Count - 1
                sFields = sFields & "," & adoRS.Fields(iField).Name
            Next

            sValues = sValues & "," & .Range("A" & iRow).Value
            sValues = sValues & "," & .Range("B" & iRow).Value
            sValues = sValues & "," & .Range("C" & iRow).Value
            sValues = sValues & "," & .Range("D" & iRow).Value

            sFields = Right(sFields, Len(sFields) - 1) 'Removing ,
            sValues = Right(sValues, Len(sValues) - 1) 'Removing ,
            adoRS.AddNew FieldList = sFields, Values:=sValues
        Next
End With

    adoRS.UpdateBatch adAffectAllChapters

    adoRS.Close
    adoConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: are you tyrying to update a SQL Server db using ADO, or retrieve data from SQL Server into an Excel spreadsheet - please clarify

Comment: Also could you clarify the RDBMS you are using (eg SQL Server 2008)?

Comment: I am trying to update a SQL Server database using ADO. I am using SQL Server 2008(Enterprise Edition).

Comment: you can create a recordset and update() it

Comment: @mehow, now i am following that approach only. But it is bit time consuming process.

Comment: is it? then you are doing something wrong bud. Create a single procedure that creates a recordset ( like iterate through records with a loop ) then update(). I dont even think it gets any easier than that honestly

Comment: @mehow could you please see my edit. There i have pasted my code.

Comment: Another way (from the database point of view) would be SSIS package which will pull data from excel sheet to db.

Comment: i think we have a little misunderstanding here;) I meant a recordset object like: Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset, let excel handle the creation and then simply update the object into the database. you are now inserting each query separately thats why it takes ages.
take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: follow @mehow's idea, you should be able to update hundreds of records in one step by using the **UpdateBatch** method of the _ADO Recordset_ object...

Comment: I put an answer using an ADO Recordset, just change tablename in the query to the correct table and make sure the columns in the worksheet are in the same order and datatype as the columns in the table

Comment: for ADO Recordset help see [MSDN Library - ADO Recordset, UpdateBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms675283(v=vs.85).aspx) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_updatebatch.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Sub InitialExport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
'
Dim adoConn             As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS               As ADODB.Recordset
'
Dim sQuery              As String
Dim EffectedRecs        As Long
Dim sFields             As String
Dim sValues             As String
'
Dim iRow                As Integer
Dim iField              As Integer
'
ServerName = SERVER_NAME
'
sQuery="SELECT * from tableName where 1 =2" ' get an empty recordset!
'
'Set the connection and open
with adoConn
    .ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING
    .Provider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.12.0"
    .cursorlocation=aduseclient
    .Open
end with
'
' set the Recordset and open
With adoRS
    .activeconnection=adoconn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
    .CursorType = adopenkeyset ' adOpenDynamic
    .Source = sQuery
    .Open
End With
'
' now get the data into the recordset
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export")
    For iRow = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
        ' here loop through all the columns
        For iField = 0 To adoRS.Fields.Count - 1
            ' adding the column names to the Variable sFields
            sFields = sFields & "," & adoRS.Fields(iField).Name
            '
            ' adding the values from the worksheet for this row
            sValues = sValues & ", " & .Cells(iRow, iField).Text
        Next
        '
        ' add a new record with the fields and values
        adoRS.AddNew FieldList:=sFields, Values:=sValues
        '
Next
'
' update all the rows in one step
adoRS.UpdateBatch adAffectAllChapters ' update them all in one step!
'
End Sub
```

just change **tablename** in the query to the correct table and make sure the columns in the worksheet are in the same order and datatype as the columns in the table

for ADO Recordset help see:

[MSDN Library - ADO Recordset, AddNew method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and

[MSDN Library - ADO Recordset, UpdateBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms675283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_updatebatch.asp)

I hope that get's you started!

Philip

Comment: here is another example of doing Batch updates on the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms675835(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: BTW, maybe you should not be giving us the IP address, user name and password :) That's all a hacker needs :)

Comment: @ philip, yeah philip but i put some random credentials here.:-) Thank you. I tried your code with a sample db table which has 4 columns(ID,Name,Currency,Rate) unfortunately i am getting RunTime error '3265' Application-defined or object-defined error. Could you see my new edit please.

Comment: `adoRS.AddNew FieldList = sFields, Values:=sValues` this statement giving me an error.

Comment: try it now, I had left off the colon in _adoRS.AddNew Fields:=sFields_

Comment: No, before posting my edit i had put colon and tried but it gave me same error:-(

Comment: `sValues = sValues & ", " & Cells(iRow, iField).Text` is missing a `.` to relate it to the `With ... End With` block. Should be: `sValues = sValues & ", " & .Cells(iRow, iField).Text`

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be uploading your entire Excel Sheet as a csv file directly into the server using [BulkInsert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

The Sql code might look as simple as this:

```
BULK INSERT [DB].[dbo].[Importa_Aux] FROM '\\share\filename.csv' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' , FIRSTROW = 2 )
```

Then simply work your data updates in SqlServer.